# jenkins use old data when running new container

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I am using docker based jenkins. My job has many stages, in one of them I create new image (I check it create correct image with new data). In the next stage, I run the command with docker agent inside the previously created image. But it has different data (old data) in compare with running image outside of jenkins (without jenkins, directly in terminal).
I removed the Jenkins_home/ directory and the problem resolved.
Now I want to know why jenkins mount old data to new image and how can I solve my problem automatically after each building new image.

Comment: Put here Dockerfile examples, docker run commands. Otherwise is hard to help!

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis I think it is not related to Dockerfile, because Image built correctly, I think problem related to volume mounting in jenkins run command

Comment: did you tried to build in jekins with `--no-cache`

Comment: @Adiii thank you for your contribution. I answer my question and post it.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis  thank you for your contribution. I answer my question and post it.

Answer (score 2):

I found reason: I did not use deletedir() function in post section in jenkinsfile. So in new builds, jenkins mount volume with old data to new container. 
reading  this link help me to find solution.[this link help me to find solution](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/)